# Blender export collada with normal map

Tags: export, collada

I'm trying to export a collada file including maps, diffuse and specular work fine but normal map doesn't, I'm using the blender internal, I know exporting from cycles doesn't work, I check 'include material maps' when exporting, I set the normal map as 'normal' in the geometry section, I set the mapping, I even made the edit in the text editor like said in this thread:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62245/blender-exporting-to-collada-assimp-and-normal-maps

This is the text of my file:

```
 <library_effects>
<effect id="Material-effect">
  <profile_COMMON>
    <newparam sid="Diff_png-surface">
      <surface type="2D">
        <init_from>Diff_png</init_from>
      </surface>
    </newparam>
    <newparam sid="Diff_png-sampler">
      <sampler2D>
        <source>Diff_png-surface</source>
      </sampler2D>
    </newparam>
    <newparam sid="Spec-surface">
      <surface type="2D">
        <init_from>Spec</init_from>
      </surface>
    </newparam>
    <newparam sid="Spec-sampler">
      <sampler2D>
        <source>Spec-surface</source>
      </sampler2D>
    </newparam>
    <newparam sid="Normal-surface">
      <surface type="2D">
        <init_from>Normal</init_from>
      </surface>
    </newparam>
    <newparam sid="Normal-sampler">
      <sampler2D>
        <source>Normal-surface</source>
      </sampler2D>
    </newparam>
    <technique sid="common">
      <phong>
        <emission>
          <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
        </emission>
        <ambient>
          <color sid="ambient">0 0 0 1</color>
        </ambient>
        <diffuse>
          <texture texture="Diff_png-sampler" texcoord="UVMap"/>
        </diffuse>
        <specular>
          <texture texture="Spec-sampler" texcoord="UVMap"/>
        </specular>
        <shininess>
          <float sid="shininess">50</float>
        </shininess>
        <index_of_refraction>
          <float sid="index_of_refraction">1</float>
        </index_of_refraction>
      </phong>
      <extra>
        <technique profile="FCOLLADA">
          <bump>
            <texture texture="Normal-sampler" texcoord="UVMap"/>
          </bump>
        </technique>
      </extra>
    </technique>
  </profile_COMMON>
</effect>
```